# VIEW intent from a Content Provider URI?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have some requirements to protect some sensitive data. The data is downloaded as a PDF from a URL and saved as an Application Private file using the following code:

```
public File downloadPDF(final Context fileContext, Uri reportUri, final String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(reportUri.toString());

        File file = httpClient.execute(get, new ResponseHandler<File>()
        {
            @Override
            public File handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
            {
                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                {
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(fileContext.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE));
                    return fileContext.getFileStreamPath(fileName);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });

        return file;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to download report.", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now, what I'd like to do is change this to using Context.MODE_PRIVATE and create a ContentProvider so that my application has complete control over the sharing of this file to a PDF reader such as Adobe Reader. Is this possible? I currently use code like the following to pass the report URI to the currently configured PDF reader.

```
    // Fire up a PDF viewer intent for the URL.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Would the same work through a ContentProvider type URI? A content://package/fileid type URI? I'll be trying a little spike tomorrow to see if I can, but if anyone knows that only file:// URIs are allowed, it would be really helpful.

---

**UPDATE**

I was able to solve my problem satisfactorily by implementing a ContentProvider subclass with the following method overridden:

```
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    // The filename is the path in the URI without the initial slash.
    String fileName = uri.getPath().substring(1);
    File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName);
    return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
}
```

Then, when I fire off the viewing intent, it is rewritten something like the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("content://providername/"),filePath);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in my case, I use Adobe Reader, which properly implements the loading from `content://` URIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would the same work through a ContentProvider type URI? A content://package/fileid type URI?

It should. You will need to have your `ContentProvider` return `application/pdf` for `getType()`. And, it is possible that some PDF readers won't handle `content://` `Uri` values.

What you can do is make the `ContentProvider`, then use `PackageManager` to see if anything will understand your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on the `content://` `Uri`. If something responds, you're set. If not, you can fall back to making the file be world-readable and using your current implementation. Or, since changing the file to world-readable may be a pain, you could run the test early on (e.g., when your app starts) with some scrap `Uri` that your `ContentProvider` supports, so you will know which route to take when you do your downloads.

Comment: Thanks very much. I intend to spend my morning working on a proof of concept to see if `content://` URIs are accepted by the PDF readers I commonly use. I didn't know about this use of the `PackageManager` either, so I'll have a read about it.

Comment: Yes, it seems that's what's happening. I peeked at the 'source' for the Adobe Reader to see if it will use a Content Resolver in the case of a `VIEW content:// Intent` and it seems that it actually will. I'm trying to figure out now why my ContentProvider is not being called back.

Comment: Okay, I've just figured out that I need to override the openFile method on my ContentProvider instance in order to intercept Adobe Reader's request for the input stream. I'm encouraged.

Comment: @Thorinside: Oh, yeah, that's how it is going to get the PDF. It has no other way to do so. I assumed your content provider already had that -- sorry for not pointing it out.

Comment: No problem, there was a bit of a learning curve to this for me anyway, so it's good that I was able to figure it out myself. I'll update the 'resolution' of this when I'm finished with this challenge. I definitely got it working and was able to set the permissions to MODE_PRIVATE as desired, so I'm happy with the outcome. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Thorinside +1 for explicitly saying that Adobe Reader supports content providers.  The default Samsung app didn't which was my problem. :(

Comment: @PeterCarpenter Yeah, don't tell anyone, but I had to decompile their app to discover that it did support content providers.

Answer (score 1):

**No content providers do not protect files**

In fact probably the first thing an app might do with a file from a content provider is make a temporary copy in its cache dir.  I think you should revisit this.